# Deal with Radio Buttons in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, type-conversion, radio-button, registration

**Problem**: I have a table `categories` on my database  which contains the *cat_id* as primary key of type int and *cat_name* as name of the category. But I collect info from the under via radio.

**Question**: How can I convert the 'on' and 'off' from the user to integers?

**Error Given**:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error:
>   1366 Incorrect integer value: 'on' for column 'type' at row 1 (SQL:
>   insert into `users` (`user_name`, `name`, `type`, `email`, `password`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (malico, John Doe, on,
>   john.doe@gmail.com,
>   $2y$10$yyf4Vt01ukTNPFxGa1PIheJZvmcPbozGjdz8zo84vkK325Qk6rfna,
>   2018-05-19 12:56:01, 2018-05-19 12:56:01))

Answer (score 0):

just do something like this on your request :

```
$request->merge(['type'=>$request->get('type') == 'on' ? 1 : 0]);
```

this will change "on" to 1 in your request